# Java & PHP - preg_match

Tags: java, php, preg-match

What is the exact equivalent of PHP preg_match($pattern, $text) in JAVA ?

I got different result for same text input as well as regex pattern in following php & java program.

Regex - \b(?:(?>cancer()|problem()|(?>\1|\2)\w+)\b\W*?){0,3}\1\2 
do match term -"cancer problem" within number Of words. here this is {0,3}

### PHP

```
<?php
$text      = "doctors found many cancer related chest problems in japan during second world war."; 
$pattern   = "/\\b(?:(?>cancer()|problem()|(?>\\1|\\2)\\w+)\\b\\W*?){0,3}\\1\\2/i";

if (preg_match($pattern, $text)) {
    echo 'matched<br>';

} else {
    echo 'not matched<br>';        
}
?>
```

What is the exact equivalent of JAVA implementation of above program ?

### I got different result for same text input as well as regex pattern in following java program.

### JAVA

```
package com.regex.test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MatchTermWithin_1 {

    final static String string = "doctors found many cancer related chest problems in japan during second world war.";

    final static String regex = "\\b(?:(?>cancer()|problem()|(?>\\1|\\2)\\w+)\\b\\W*?){0,3}\\1\\2";        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0)+"\n");
        for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }else {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }


    if(matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("matched "+"\n");
    }else {
        System.out.println("not matched " + "\n");
    }

    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it works as expected in PHP? What are the requirements for the pattern?

Comment: Let say you have a term with two words eg :- "cancer problem"
then that term need to be matched within the given distance. for an example.
we have a text "no cancer since problem morning testing my reports" then above two words term need to matched within a distance specified by regex. here it's {0,3} 
full java regex  - \\b(?:(?>cancer()|problem()|(?>\\1|\\2)\\w+)\\b\\W*?){0,3}\\1\\2

Comment: Do you need to also match these words in any order? Do you need it to be scalable to more than two words? You might use something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/fJZ1wi/1).

Comment: Do you need to also match these words in any order? No,
Do you need it to be scalable to more than two words? Yes.

 that need to be matched as "cancer xxxx yyyy zzzz problem" where generic regex is 
\\b(?:(?>cancer()|problem()|(?>\\1|\\2)\\w+)\\b\\W*?){0,x}\\1\\2
where x is the distance within a given text.

Comment: Well, sounds like you may simplify that even to [`\bcancer(?:\W+\w+){0,1}\W+problem\b`](https://regex101.com/r/fJZ1wi/2). Just adjust the maxinum threshold.

Comment: Try with this you can understand the context I need.
https://regex101.com/
  regex - \b(?:(?>cancer()|problem()|(?>\1|\2)\w+)\b\W*?){0,3}\1\2
   text - no cancer since problem morning testing my reports

Comment: I understand. I already suggested an alternative. It is matching a specific number of words between two whole words.

Comment: I need to be honest with you solution it's not met my requirement. but I appreciate you.

Comment: Above php script gives me a right answer but I need to implement same solution in java.

Comment: Different regex flavors treat unmatched groups differently. PHP does not initialize the backreference values, but Java seems to be doing that. That means you need to change the approach rather than trying to make the same regex work in another flavor.

Comment: that's a good point. but I'm stuck with how same regex need to be implemented in another flavor/ different manner.

Comment: You might never get an answer if you do not explain what the regex should do *clearly* and *inside the question itself*. People rarely read such lengthy comments.

Comment: regex - \\b(?:(?>cancer()|problem()|(?>\\1|\\2)\\w+)\\b\\W*?){0,3}\\1\\2 
- do match Term Within Number Of Words

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution for this. hope this may be a clue for other expertise in Java & PHP.

```
package com.ae.text.processor;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class ProximitySearch {

    public static boolean MatchTermWithinNumberOfWords(String text, String term, int distance) {

    String[] term_words = term.split(" ");
    String[] right_side_array;
    String right_side = "";
    String tmp = "";

    if (text.contains(term_words[0])) {
        String[] splitted_search_words = text.split(term_words[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < splitted_search_words.length; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            right_side = splitted_search_words[1];
            if (right_side.contains(term_words[1])) {
            right_side_array = right_side.split(" ");
            int indexOfSecondTerm = ArrayUtils.indexOf(right_side_array, term_words[1]);
            for (int j = 0; j <= indexOfSecondTerm; j++) {
                tmp = tmp + " " + right_side_array[j];
            }
            if (indexOfSecondTerm <= distance) {
                printMatched(term_words[0] + tmp);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    return false;
    }

    public static void printMatched(String mathed) {
    System.out.println(mathed);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "doctors found many cancer related chest problems in japan durring second world war.";
    String term = "cancer problems";
    int distance = 3;
    System.out.println(MatchTermWithinNumberOfWords(text, term, distance));
    }
}
```