# Java :- String search in proximity manner

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, search, full-text-search

I need a pure Java program to search on a given string to "find words near each other" - each-other distance need to be specified.
More specifically said :- finds word1 and word2 in any order, as long as they occur within a certain distance of each other.

For example :- to search for a "cancer" and "problems" within 3 words of each other in a given string - if found return "true" else return "false".

String term = "cancer problems";
String text = "doctors found many cancer related chest problems in japan during second world war."; 
int distance = 3; // distance may vary

I prefer pure Java solution rather regex solution.

Comment: "I prefer pure Java solution rather regex solution." - and we prefer you showing us what you have tried so far so we can help you fix a problem. We are not solving the entire task for you.

Comment: @luk2302 All OP has is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598271/java-php-preg-match), I guess.

Comment: Please follow the 
String text = "doctors found many cancer related problems in japan durring second world war.";

regex approach 1 : -
\\bcancer\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){1,6}?problems\\b 

regex approach 2 :-
\b(?:(?>cancer()|problems()|(?>\1|\2)\w+)\b\W*?){0,2}\1\2\b

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew
Thanks for your mention. your noted it previously.

Comment: And your question is still unclear, sorry.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - Please leave it to other community people if you can't understand. Thanks.

Comment: I have. Others think your question is too broad and they gave you 2 downvotes. Not me.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew it's Ok I'm not counting reputation it doesn't matter for me no hard feeling about. I'm actually stuck on this Java problem that's why I'm asking community support. I already have php solution but I need implement it on Java platform too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very naive way without regex.

```
public class NotElegant {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String text = "doctors found many cancer related chest problems in japan during second world war.";
        String term = "cancer problems";
        System.out.println(getWordsNearEachOther(text,term,3));
    }
    public static String getWordsNearEachOther(String text, String term, int distance){
        String word1= term.split(" ")[0];
        String word2= term.split(" ")[1];
        String firstWord = text.indexOf(word1)<text.indexOf(word2)?word1:word2;
        String secondWord = text.indexOf(word1)<text.indexOf(word2)?word2:word1;
        if(!(text.contains(word1) && text.contains(word2))){
            return null;
        }        
        else if(text.substring(text.indexOf(firstWord), text.indexOf(secondWord)+secondWord.length()).split(" ").length>distance+1){
            return null;
        }
        return text.substring(text.indexOf(firstWord), text.indexOf(secondWord)+secondWord.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually acceptable. may be now I have some good approach. it's actually better one.Thanks for @Eritrean